# Shell Commands for System Administration, and gudie to Vi editor

Tags: command-line, vi

I'm very much interested in shell commands

In fact,I know some basic commands.

But I want to learn more about them.

Are there any good resources?

I'm interested to learn more about vi editor too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are very many that i don't even know some but the basics can be gotten 
Here download [ubuntu guide to terminal usage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)  or download this [simple pdf version](http://fcitr.kau.edu.sa/GetFile.aspx?id=60761&fn=Linux.pdf)
from another source and get started

**Please be carefull when testing these commands**

Comment: thanks for the pdf.But is there any online course available? :)

Comment: not sure but will inform you as soon as i find out

Answer (score 0):

Linux commands i very useful when GUI doesn't fit your needs to customize the system , yes my friend you should start learning commands.

Here is a good site [Here](http://linuxtutorial.todolistme.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Linux Administration You should attend [LPIC](http://www.lpi.org/linux-certifications/programs) course or watch any [LPIC youtube videos](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lpic)

Regarding VI it's enough to save [this reference card](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/Vi%20Reference%20Card.pdf)